# How differs the open pragma with different utf8?

Tags: perl, utf-8

Do these three versions all behave differently?

```
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );  
use open qw( :encoding(UTF8) :std );  
use open qw( :utf8 :std );
```

Comment: This [Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html) may have the answer, or at least be helpful to you.

Comment: The Perl Unicode Cookbook is the reason why I am asking this. Until now I used `use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );` and I thought it would by the "better" choice. But now I have seen that the Author of the book uses `use open qw(:std :utf8);` and I suppose he knows what he is doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, `:utf8` only markes the text as UTF-8 it does not check that it is valid. See [this post on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=626470) for information.

`:encoding` is an Extension Layer to PerlIO, perl `perldoc perliol`

> ":encoding" use Encoding;
>   makes this layer available, although PerlIO.pm "knows" where to find it. It is an example of a layer which takes an argument as it is called thus: open( $fh, "<:encoding(iso-8859-7)", $pathname );

The other two questions are answered in the FAQ `perldoc perlunifaq`

> **What is the difference between ":encoding" and ":utf8"?** Because UTF-8 is one of Perl's internal formats, you can often just skip the encoding or decoding step, and manipulate the UTF8 flag directly. Instead of ":encoding(UTF-8)", you can simply use ":utf8", which skips the encoding step if the data was already represented as UTF8 internally. This is widely accepted as good behavior when you're writing, but it can be dangerous when reading, because it causes internal inconsistency when you have invalid byte sequences. Using ":utf8" for input can sometimes result in security breaches, so please use ":encoding(UTF-8)" instead. Instead of "decode" and "encode", you could use "_utf8_on" and "_utf8_off", but this is considered bad style. Especially "_utf8_on" can be dangerous, for the same reason that ":utf8" can. There are some shortcuts for oneliners; see "-C" in perlrun.
>
> **What's the difference between "UTF-8" and "utf8"?** "UTF-8" is the official standard. "utf8" is Perl's way of being liberal in what it accepts. If you have to communicate with things that aren't so liberal, you may want to consider using "UTF-8". If you have to communicate with things that are too liberal, you may have to use "utf8". The full explanation is in Encode. "UTF-8" is internally known as "utf-8-strict". The tutorial uses UTF-8 consistently, even where utf8 is actually used internally, because the distinction can be hard to make, and is mostly irrelevant. For example, utf8 can be used for code points that don't exist in Unicode, like 9999999, but if you encode that to UTF-8, you get a substitution character (by default; see "Handling Malformed Data" in Encode for more ways of dealing with this.) Okay, if you insist: the "internal format" is utf8, not UTF-8. (When it's not some other encoding.)

The `open` pragma (ie., `use open`) only sets the *default PerlIO layers for input and output*; `:std` does the following,

> The ":std" subpragma on its own has no effect, but if combined with the ":utf8" or ":encoding" subpragmas, it converts the standard filehandles (STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR) to comply with encoding selected for input/output handles.  For example, if both input and out are chosen to be ":encoding(utf8)", a ":std" will mean that STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR are also in ":encoding(utf8)".  On the other hand, if only output is chosen to be in ":encoding(koi8r)", a ":std" will cause only the STDOUT and STDERR to be in "koi8r".  The ":locale" subpragma implicitly turns on ":std".

So `:std` is a subpragma (open.pm specific) that sets the Standard Streams to receive Unicode Input perl `:utf8` as above.

Comment: So what would you recommend, `use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) )` or `use open qw( :std :utf8 )` ? According to the above, the latter is considered dangerous when reading, but still it is recommended by @tchrist in the [Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html). Any reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

Evan seems to have your answer. For future ease of use see [`uft8::all`](https://metacpan.org/module/utf8%3a%3aall), *"turn on Unicode - all of it"*.