# How to get a defined ${^OPEN}?

Tags: perl, character-encoding, special-variables

What changes are required in this code to get a defined  `${^OPEN}`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );

print ${^OPEN};
```

---

```
Use of uninitialized value $^OPEN in print at ./perl.pl line 6.
```

Comment: Why do you want to inspect that?

Comment: I would like to know if `binmode STDIN ':encoding(...)` is set. If is set I would let return a subroutine decoded strings else not decoded strings.

Comment: @sid_com, check `PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDIN, details => 1)`.

Comment: @tobyink, this way doesn't look beautiful to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite uneasy way.  May be it is better to user more readable Perl.

`:utf8` outputs utf-8 charset but does not checks its validity, you should not use this one, except for one liners.  Use `:encoding(UTF-8)` instead.

Please refer to this post [How differs the open pragma with different utf8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566460/how-differs-the-open-pragma-with-different-utf8) for more information about different types of utf-8 input/outputs.

I even do not know what could possibly be `${^OPEN}` variable.  I advice you not to use it at all, as you should not use magic punctuation.

Hope it helps